# Postgres query to fetch both masters and slaves

Tags: sql, postgresql

Probably bad title, sorry for that.
This is the situation:

Users-table:

```
id
name
```

Connections-table:

```
id
master_id
slave_id


insert into Users values(1,'Jack');
insert into Users values(2,'Marc');
insert into Users values(3,'Susie');
insert into Users values(4,'Paul');

insert into Connections values(1,1,2);
insert into Connections values(2,3,1);
insert into Connections values(3,3,4);
```

With the above inserts, Jack has Marc as slave.
But he is Susie's slave too.
Even Paul is Susie's slave.

Now I need to fetch all the people that are Jack's slaves. But I also need to fetch jack's masters and that master's slaves.

In english it would mean that for jack I would get all the users in the table. As Marc is Jack's slave. Susie is Jack's master.
And Paul is Susie's slave (and Susie was Jack's master, so Paul is in some way in my list of users I belong too in some way).

Hope this was quite clear.

Is it possible to get all this in one query?
Right now there is a query that fetches all the Jack's slaves. I built one for getting all the Jack's masters. But then I would need to loop each master to get all his slaves. All this would generate at least 3 queries.
As Im using node.js with all the callback stuff it is not really a good option.
I was thinking about UNION but Im not sure it is the way to go. And also stored procedure, I would prefer to avoid them.

Actually, using UNION I can select both the rows where Im slave and those where Im master. But I still don't know how to fetch those rows where my masters are master_id.

---EDIT---

I am running this query now:

```
select
"connections"."master_id"
,"connections"."slave_id"
from
"connections"
where
"connections"."master_id" = 1
union
select
"connections"."master_id"
,"connections"."slave_id"
from
"connections"
where
"connections"."slave_id" = 1    
union
select
"connections"."master_id"
,"connections"."slave_id"
from
"connections"
where
"connections"."master_id" IN 
(select "connections"."master_id" from "connections" where "connections"."slave_id" = 1)
```

It seems it is giving me the expected result.
Which in this case would be all the rows in the table connections.
Do you think it looks correct?

Comment: What is the output you expect from that sample data?

Comment: I edited the question even adding what I think could be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of scenario where a Recursive CTE is very helpful. A recursive CTE is a special CTE that refers back to itself. We use it for traversing hierarchies instead of making a bunch of self joins, which is generally a bad option when the depth of the hierarchy is fluid across it's different paths, and over time.

```
WITH RECURSIVE recCTE() AS
(
    /*Recursive Seed - The start of the recursive lookup*/
    SELECT
        master_id as parent,
        slave_id as child,
        /*You can use "depth" to check how deep we are in the master/slave hierarchy*/
        1 as Depth,
        /*You can use a "path" to see which people/nodes are involved in the hierarchy as it's built through the iterations of the recursive CTE*/
        CAST(master_id || '>' || child as VARCHAR(50)) as path
    FROM
        Connections
    WHERE
        /* here we determine who we are starting with for the lookup. You could start with everyone by omitting this*/
        /* We'll start with Susie */
        master_id = 3


    /*
        Recursive Term - The part of the query that refers to itself and iterates until
        the inner join fails
    */
    SELECT
        recCTE.child as parent,
        connections.slave_id as child,
        recCTE.depth + 1 as depth,
        recCTE.path || '>' || connections.slave_id as path
    FROM
        recCTE /*referred to itself here*/
        INNER JOIN connections ON
            recCTE.child = connections.master_id /*Join child to master for next lookup of slave/child */
    WHERE
        /*safe guard in case of endless cycling (A reporting to B reporting to C reporting back to A)*/
        recCTE.Depth < 15 

        /*besides checking for depth, you could also insure that the slave doesn't exist in the path already*/
        recCTE.path NOT LIKE '%' || slave_id || '%'


)

/*Now select from it and see what you get*/
SELECT * FROM recCTE;
```

[Check out the official Postgres documentation on Recursive CTEs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Please, could you have a look at the edited question? I came up with a solution that seems is giving me the expected result. But Im not fully sure its the best one.

Comment: Yours will work fine (as would a self join in a single query), but once your hierarchy gets more than 1 or 2 deep, you are going to end up with a hell of a union query. For sake of scale, you should consider recursive. This way if Susie is master to Jack who is master Paul who is master to Marc, you can run this for Susie and get Marc in the output.

Comment: Well as im using sequelize for node.js and as it seems that "with" isnt supported, then i wonder if the unions i wrote will always give all the rows no matter the depth.

Comment: But of course i understand the concerne with scaling and will investigate in it.

Comment: Yours won't work with more than a depth of 3. It will get the master record, the slave's records and the slave's slave's records. You will have to keep adding for each level of depth that you want to hit. But.. either a lot of LEFT JOIN's back to the same table, or the UNION with correlated subqueries is going to be your only bet if you can't do a recursive CTE.